# IOS CallKit Audio issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

i have developed ios voip applicaion using pjsip Lib. in this app incomming view i am using callkit with pushkit here audio and mic not working in ios 10.2 version

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell the reason from your description. But I once had audio issue dealing with CallKit. One thing to be careful is that you should manage your audio session settings only in

`- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider didActivateAudioSession:(AVAudioSession *)audioSession`

and

`- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider didDeactivateAudioSession:(AVAudioSession *)audioSession`

If you happened to manage your audio session settings or audio unit stuff else where, it may cause a lot of different audio problems.

Comment: @Elvin.In my case didActivateAudioSession and didDeactivateAudioSession method are calling inside this methods anything has to do.

Answer (score 0):

For incoming SIP call, make sure that until user answers the call, the call audio I/O **is not running**. This is crucial stuff.

When `CXProvider` responds with

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction)
```

Configure `AVAudioSession` there (set sample rate to 44100, buffer to 0.0005 and category PlayAndRecord with mode of VoiceChat)

fulfill the action, which will elevate the `AVAudioSession` priority and `CXProvider` will respond with

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didActivate audioSession: AVAudioSession)
```

There you start call audio processor (for pjsip, it's someting like `pjsua_set_snd_dev(-1, -2)`)

Make sure to stop sound device when CXProvider responds with

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didDeactivate audioSession: AVAudioSession)
```

And it is recommended to stop sound device in `sip_init()`, like `pjsua_set_no_snd_dev()` when using CallKit